# Swift pattern matching

Tags: swift, generic-constraints

In the code below:

```
protocol Serializable {
}

struct Owner: Serializable {
   var name: String
}

struct Car: Serializable {
   var owners: [Serializable]
}

let car = Car(owners: [Owner(name: "John"), Owner(name: "Mike")])

Mirror(reflecting: car).children.forEach {
   switch $0.value {
   case let value as Array<Serializable>:
      print("Recognized!")
   default: break
   }
}
```

if in

```
struct Car: Serializable {
   var owners: [Serializable]
}
```

(owners var is defined as `[Serializable]`)

`case let value as Array<Serializable>:` will recognise it, but in case:

```
struct Car: Serializable {
   var owners: [Owner]
}
```

(owners var is defined as `[Owner]`)

`case let value as Array<Serializable>:` will not recognise it, although `Owner` conforms to `Serializable` protocol?
Can somebody explain why?

I tried:

```
extension Array where Element: Serializable {
   var representation: AnyObject {
      return self.map { element in return "String" }
   }
}

let arr: [Owner] = [Owner(name: "John"), Owner(name: "Mike")]
arr.representation
```

works, so Swift recognises that `[Owner]` is `[Serializable]`, why does `case let value as Array<Serializable>` match `[Serializable]` but not `[Owner]`?

Comment: Have you tried `case let value where value is Array<Serializable>`?

Comment: It doesn't work. Works the same as `case let value as Array<Serializable>`

Comment: Somebody deleted a reply. He mentioned that this won't compile: let arr: [Owner] = [Owner(name: "John"), Owner(name: "Mike")]; let arr2 = arr as? Array<Serializable> ... Error: Serializable is not a subtype of Owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, protocols have a different and separate memory representation than concrete types. So the short answer is the an array of `Serializable` is different in memory than an array of a type that conforms to `Serializable`, and Swift does not currently have a mechanism of casting between the two.

More specific, nitty-gritty details in this WWDC talk:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/

Comment: Thanks Daniel, will check the video

Answer (score 0):

`Array<T>` and `T` are different types, so you can't expect one's conformance to a protocol to have any bearing on the other.

With regards to your example:

```
extension Array where Element: Serializable {
   var representation: AnyObject {
      return self.map { element in return "String" }
   }
}
```

Here, you're checking for the conformance of *each element* (`Element`), not the Array as its own type. `Element` is a separate type than `Array<Element>`.

It's hard to know what you should be doing here instead without more information, but I hope I've answered why you're not getting the results you might expect.

Comment: You're right about `extension Array where Element: Serializable` ... Array<T> and T are different types ..., but what's strange to me is that Swift recognises that [Owner] is [Serializable] since Owner implements Serializable but I can't use [Owner] in case statement.

Comment: `Array<Owner>` and `Array<Serializable>` are not the same. The only reason the extension works is because the element's type--and not the generic itself--is tested for conformance. `Owner` is `Serializable`, but that's it.